# Docker on Rails test stop working after I did a docker system prune

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I got a Rails app working with docker for my local development and was working fine until yesterday I run `docker system prune` and deleted some files as I was running out of space. Since the whenever I try to test or run my app I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
PG::ConnectionBad:
  fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

This still works fine on my laptop (where I didn't run `docker system prune`). Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4.1
    volumes:
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=minerva_api_test
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust

  web:
    build: .
    command: bin/rails server --port 3000 --binding 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/minerva
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=db

volumes:
  postgres:
```

And here's my `database.yml`:

```
test:
  <<: *default
  database: mydb_test
  host: db
  username: postgres
  password: ''
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Just a quick guess - did you try to delete `password` from `database.yml`?

Comment: @JanMatuszewski You mean completely removing the line `password: ''`? Yes I have tried but still got the same error